# Get particular type from object

Tags: c#

How do I get all the date time type present in an object?

E.G. shipment object contains all the details about the shipment such as name of shipper,consignee etc. It also contain many date time fields such as received date, transported date, delivered date etc.

How could I get all the date fields of the shipment object?

Comment: Whats the code you have?

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest approach would be to directly access the properties e.g.

```
var receivedDate = shipment.ReceivedDate;
var transportedDate = shipment.DeliveryDate;
...
```

An alternative approach would be to have your `Shipment` object return the list for you e.g.

```
public Dictionary<string, DateTime> Dates
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, DateTime>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>("ReceivedDate", ReceivedDate),
            new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>("DeliveryDate", DeliveryDate),
            ...
        }
    }
}

...
foreach (var d in shipment.Dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Key, d.Value);
}
```

Or lastly, use Reflection to iterate over the properties:

```
public Dictionary<string, DateTime> Dates
{
    get
    {
        return from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
               where p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)
               select new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(p.Name, (DateTime)p.GetValue(this, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinking about SoC, I would disrecommend using the 'return the list for you' approach!

Comment: @Aphelion - I don't really see where there is a SoC problem is here. The properties already belong to the object therefore there is no reason why the object can't return a list of them (for whatever reason). Since the OP hasn't really said the reason they need the dates (or how many dates there are) it's difficult to see what sort of solution would be best for them.

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you. I must agree that it's difficult to see what is required. It is even unsure whether we can modify the object to provide the list.

Comment: Yeah I think @AbdulAdhar has to be more specific in what it is he is trying to do. The problem is everyone always jumps to Reflection right away for this type of solution, however, Reflection can be slow & an unnecessary overhead - that's why I put it last and gave a couple of examples how to do it without Reflection. However, sometimes Reflection *is* the right way to go...

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection.

```
    Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass); // or object.GetType()
    var dateTimeProperties = from property in myClassType.GetProperties()
                             where property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)
                             select property;
```

for more read about reflection in .net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx